# Swift 4 What is the best way to store an array of custom types persistently?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array which contains objects that each have custom and non-primitive type properties like URL and StorageReference (Firebase). What is the best way to store the contents of this array persistently? I thought of using Realm, but Realm only stores objects that have primitive type properties. The amount of objects retrieved from persistent storage will continue to increase as the app is used more because there will be more and more items to retrieve from Firebase.

Comment: coredata ..............

Comment: I think `Codable` will help.

Comment: Firebase supports offline storage. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

> Realm supports the following property types: Bool , Int , Int8 , Int16
>   , Int32 , Int64 , Double , Float , String , Date , and Data.

So, ideally you should be able to cover any custom types by converting them to a suitable primitive type.
For instance, you can save your `URL` as a `String` while saving to Realm and convert back when retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include third party frameworks you can use the Codable protocol and save things with NSKeyedArchiver. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver

Simple example:

```
struct A: Codable {
    var myString: String? // primitive types are already codable
}

struct B: Codable {
    var myInt: Int?
    var a: A? // custom types need to be Codable
}

// save  
let myObject = B()  
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myObject, toFile: "/path/to/archive")  

// load  
let myObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("/path/to/archive") as? B
```

If your custom type is more complex you might want to implement the custom encode/decode methods to have more control over how you data is saved and loaded. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types